# CreateObject() unable to resolve CFC path in CF2018

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-2018

Below is my project folder structure in CF.

```
root
|---myproject
       |-folder1
           |-file1.cfc
           |-file2.cfc
       |- folder2
           |-file3.cfc
           |-file4.cfc
```

I have a function in file2.cfc, in which I am using createObject() function to create an object for file3.cfc . Below is the example of code am using.

```
var fileObj = createObject("component", "folder2.file3").init(argument1, argument2);
```

I recently upgraded my CF server from CF2016 to CF2018. When my application was running on CF2016, object creation was happening, but on CF2018 no object creation is happening.
Can some one please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: You likely had a mapping before that was pointing to folder2. Otherwise you path should be relative to the root.

Comment: @haxtbh : No changes has been done in Application.cfc and also the mappings are same as it was for CF2016 in the CF Administrator.

Comment: Did you move to a new server or just upgrade CF in-place? Have you checked the IIS virtual mappings? If you moved servers, maybe those weren't migrated.

Comment: What error is being thrown on object instantiation?

Comment: Could also be mappings setup in the CF admin.

Comment: I’d check a couple of things. 1. If you moved to the new server, check if there is some logic that is causing the mappings to fail (path to cfc) 2. Any environment variables/conditions are now looking or not picking up the mappings. Either ways, only an actual error description or screenshot will help.

Comment: <cfset this.mappings["/cfc"] = GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath() )&"cfc"> is this the mapping you are talking about @akashb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var fileObj = new folder2.file3().init(argument1, argument2);
```

or if the root is / and "myproject" is a folder inside of root

```
var fileObj = new myproject.folder2.file3().init(argument1, argument2);
```